# Why do I need to use URL Fingerprinting with far-future expires headers on static assets?

Tags: apache, iis, browser, http-headers, browser-cache

Everything I read about "expires" headers (http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/, eg) indicates that when taking advantage of caching in this manner, you need to "fingerprint" your file names so that when your static assets change, the browser will stop using the version from cache and instead fetch the new one.

However, in my tests with IIS7 as the backend webserver, and using IE 7, FF, and Chrome browsers, I did not need to do so. If I changed the file on the webserver -- something like "myfile.js", then the webserver sent the "last modified" header as that file's date of modification, and the browsers all picked up on that change. They returned a 200 for the first request after changing the file and subsequent requests appeared to pull from cache.

So surely I'm missing something, but I don't know what it is.  Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your testing is flawed. You're likely hitting the "Reload" button, but that is not the way users typically load your site - instead they click on a link, hit a bookmark, type the URL, etc. Some people hit reload but it's a very small percentage.

When you hit Reload you're forcing the browser to send the If-Modified-Since request. If instead you have a far future Expires date and load the page in a typical fashion, you'll see that the browser does not make any HTTP request for that resource - which is good!

See this blog post for more info (paragraph 4): http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2011/06/27/unexpected-reloads-in-webkit/

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers will still attempt to fetch any requested URL from the server, but include a 'If-Modified-Since' timestamp in the request. The server can use that to determine if it should send back a 200 OK and the contents of the requested url, or a a 304 Not Modifed response to indicate that the browser should use the cached version.

The expires header basically just tells the browser "after this point in time, you SHOULD delete your cached version and fetch a fresh copy".

Comment: So if I modify the file on October 1, 2011, and a user visits on November 1, 2011, and their browser sends an "If-Modified-Since" header of October 15, then they will *not* get that modified file? Is that the idea?

Comment: In theory, yes. Depends on if this is an 'original' fetch, in which case they'd grab the file unconditionally, and if it's still cached, etc...